# Индикатор знака рисуется поверх текста

Tags: дефект, локализация, знаки, дизайн

В списке выбора отслеживаемого знака для знака "Спортивное поведение" серебряная точка частично перекрывает первую букву названия:

[image: Спортивное поведение]

В идеале, нельзя допускать таких длинных имен, чтобы элементы пересекались, но с учетом локализации, это бывает трудно предусмотреть сразу.

Для исправления ситуации можно также отображать точку ниже текста.